# Left column 100% empty when I scroll down

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

When I make a `<div>` column 100%, and I fill it with content and then scrolling down the background is empty.

But when the `<div>` is empty I also want it to be height 100% so that you see the background from top to bottom.

Does someone know why and how to solve this?

- [example here with scroll](http://jsfiddle.net/KfjGU/122/)
- [example here without scroll](http://jsfiddle.net/KfjGU/132/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to make the page 100% in height, and also ensure the `div` is at least as tall as the page. So, use this:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#fullheight {
    min-height: 100% !important;
    width: 250px;
    background: blue;
}
```

This ensures that the `fullheight` div is not constrained to only 100%, and that the page is at least full height.

Fiddles: http://jsfiddle.net/KfjGU/138/, http://jsfiddle.net/KfjGU/139/

Comment: Thhx this worked like a charm for me :D you really helped me out thhx for youre time

Comment: There is only 1 more problem and that is when i put a 50 pixels margin  to the top a vertical scrollbar appears